# How to push messages from unacked to ready

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

My question is similar to a question asked previously, however it does not find an answer, I have a Consumer which I want to process an action called a Web Service, however, if this web service does not respond for some reason, I want the consumer not to process the message of the RabbitMQ but I encole it to process it later, my consumer is the following one:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/environment.rb', __FILE__)
conn=Rabbit.connect
conn.start
ch = conn.create_channel
x = ch.exchange("d_notification_ex", :type=> "x-delayed-message", :arguments=> { "x-delayed-type" => "direct"})
q  = ch.queue("d_notification_q", :durable =>true)
q.bind(x)
p 'Wait ....'
q.subscribe(:manual_ack => true, :block => true) do |delivery_info, properties, body|
 
  datos=JSON.parse(body)
  if datos['status']=='request'
    #I call a web service and process the json
    result=Notification.send_payment_notification(datos.to_json)
  else
    #I call a web service and process the body
    result=Notification.send_payment_notification(body)
  end
   #if the call to the web service, the web server is off the result will be equal to nil
   #therefore, he did not notify RabbitMQ, but he puts the message in UNACKED status
   # and does not process it later, when I want him to keep it in the queue and evaluate it afterwards.
  unless result.nil?
  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
  end

end
```

An image of RabbitMQ,

[image]

There is some way that in the statement: c hack (delivery_info.delivery_tag), this instead of deleting the element of the queue can process it later, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "I can tell you to process it later?"

Comment: @lacostenycoder excuse my english! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if result.nil?
  ch.nack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
else
  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
end
```

Comment: Very Thanks! try but it does not work, I think I'll decide to send the message back to the queue with a producer inside the consumer.

Comment: "it does not work" is not very helpful. What do you see? A nack will indicate to RabbitMQ that you would like the message re-queued [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html). If you only have one consumer, it will be re-delivered to that consumer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to send the data back to the queue with a style "producer within the consumer", my code now looks like this:

```
  if result.eql? 'ok'
  ch.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag)
  else
    if(datos['count'] < 5)
      datos['count'] += 1
      d_time=1000
      x.publish(datos.to_json,  :persistent => true, :headers=>{"x-delay" => d_time})
    end
  end
```

However I was forced to include one more attribute in the JSON attribute: Count! so that it does not stay in an infinite cycle.